# Allow multi-line String properties in the Properties window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I've got a Windows Form User Control with a string property for setting the text of a textbox.  This string *can* be multi-line.

I've noticed that on some controls with a text property, and instead of being forced to type in the single line property textbox, you get a little pop up where you can type multiple lines.  (As a matter of fact, a Windows Forms Textbox control allows this on the Text property.)

How do I enable this functionality in the properties window for the property I have designed?

*The following is not real code in my app, but an example of how such a property might be defined*

```
public string Instructions
{
   get
   {
      return TextBox1.Text;
   }
   set
   {
      TextBox1.Text = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`EditorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58aa8z15.aspx) with a [`MultilineStringEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.multilinestringeditor.aspx):

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), 
                 typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]  
public string Instructions
{
   get
   {
      return TextBox1.Text;
   }
   set
   {
      TextBox1.Text = value;
   }
}
```

To avoid adding a reference to System.Design and thus requiring the Full framework, you can also write the attribute like this:

```
[EditorAttribute(
    "System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design",
    "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor")]
```

Although this is less of a problem now that they've stopped splitting the framework into a Client Profile and a Full one.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing some references.  I am not getting the MiltilineStringEditor as an option in my Intellisense.  Even when I use System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor.  And it won't compile.  If I ca get it to work, I'll give you the credit for the right answer, though...

Comment: you have to reference `System.Design.dll`

Comment: Perfect.  I found that out on my own and was just coming back to post that as a comment.  Thank you.  I'm going to keep this open for a day or so so that hopefully you will get some votes on the answer beside my own.  This was a pretty obscure piece of knowledge, and I think you should be rewarded.

Comment: Adding a reference to System.Design requires that the target framework is not Client Profile but Full. As an alternative, write the attribute like this: `[EditorAttribute("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor")]` - this works with the Client Profile too!

Comment: @romkyns Thanks! It's ugly but certainly less ugly than having to target Full Profile for such a silly thing. I wonder who was the genius on charge of that.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Who came here looking for .NETCF, go to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475299/define-custom-design-time-editor-in-a-usercontrol-e-g-multiline-text-in-compa)