# Define custom design time editor in a usercontrol (e.g. multiline text) in compact framework 3.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework

In .NET I would just write

```
[Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public string MultiLineText { get; set; }
```

to get the multiline editor for a string property.

However, in Compact Framework this is not possible because `System.ComponentModel` is not included.
I already have a `DesigntimeAttributes.xmta` file and I suppose I have to define it here but I can't find an example on how to achive this.

Answer (score 3):

The following xmta entry does the trick on my VS2008:

```
<Property Name="MultiLineText">
  <Browsable>true</Browsable>
  <Editor>
    <BaseType>System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing</BaseType>
    <Type>System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design</Type>
  </Editor>
</Property>
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot!** どうもありがとう